# How to position a child element so that half of its height overlaps the parent's next sibling

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's my CodePen that demonstrates the closest I've gotten: https://codepen.io/will_beaumont/pen/QWmRvXW

As you can see, the white box with the Latin text has half of its height overlapping the section titled "Our Wheelhouse". The drawback is that because I'm using `position: relative` on the quote box there's all this whitespace above it. I know I could use `position: absolute`, but then I would have to figure out how to set the height on the parent section to be just right using JavaScript. It would be ideal if I could do this without JavaScript, but I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: Just remove the `margin-bottom: 47px;` to reduce the whitespace

Comment: @lxe, that doesn't reduce the margin enough, but you've given me an idea. I can set that margin to be negative and equal to half the height of the quote box. BRB, I'm gonna see if that works.

Answer (score -1):

I updated the CodePen with the fix. I subtracted half the height of the quote box from the bottom margin for the line "With over 70 years of experience...".